# React Native - Trying change 2 View heights with GestureHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to create Height adjustable Views with React Native for an app I am building. I keep getting stuck on this one aspect. I am trying to create two stacked Views, with a line inbetween them so they are height adjustable when dragging the line up or down, adjusting content in it as well. Image below is a representation of what I am trying to make. "Home Option 2" is default state, "Home Option 1.3 is when the slider is dragged down, and "Home Option 1.2" is opposite - slider dragged up.

With an app bar at the bottom. (I dont have it made yet)

Any thoughts or help is appreciated!

[image]

Here is my code for App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetRefProps } from './components/BottomSheet';
import { useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker, Geojson } from "react-native-maps";
import { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";




export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef<BottomSheetRefProps>(null);
  const [topViewHeight, setTopViewHeight] = React.useState(0);

  const onPress = useCallback(() => {
    const isActive = ref?.current?.isActive();
    if (isActive) {
      ref?.current?.scrollTo(0);
    } else {
      ref?.current?.scrollTo(-200);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.mapViewContainer}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          style={styles.mapView}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 00.00 ,
            longitude: -00.00 ,
            latitudeDelta: 00.00 ,
            longitudeDelta: 00.00 ,
          }}
        >
          <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 00.00, longitude: 00.00 }} />
        </MapView>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="light" />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress} />
        <BottomSheet ref={ref} {...{setTopViewHeight, topViewHeight}}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'orange' }} />
        </BottomSheet>
      </View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#111',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    opacity: 0.6,
  },
  mapViewContainer: {
    height: "50%",
    width: "95%",
    overflow: "hidden",
    background: "transparent",
    borderRadius: 13,
  },
  mapView: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```

Code for BottomSheet.tsx (Which i was using as a reference for the ideal UX)

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
  Extrapolate,
  interpolate,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withSpring,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get('window');

const TOP_VIEW_HEIGHT = 50;

const VIEW_RESIZE = 2.5;
const MAX_TRANSLATE_Y = -SCREEN_HEIGHT / VIEW_RESIZE;

type BottomSheetProps = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  setTopViewHeight: (height: number) => void;
  topViewHeight: number;
};

export type BottomSheetRefProps = {
  scrollTo: (destination: number) => void;
  isActive: () => boolean;
};

const BottomSheet = React.forwardRef<BottomSheetRefProps, BottomSheetProps>(
  ({ children }, ref) => {
    const translateY = useSharedValue(0);
    const active = useSharedValue(false);

    const scrollTo = useCallback((destination: number) => {
      'worklet';
      active.value = destination !== 0;

      translateY.value = withSpring(destination, { damping: 50 });
    }, []);

    const isActive = useCallback(() => {
      return active.value;
    }, []);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ scrollTo, isActive }), [
      scrollTo,
      isActive,
    ]);

    const context = useSharedValue({ y: 0 });
    const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
      .onStart(() => {
        context.value = { y: translateY.value };
      })
      .onUpdate((event) => {
        translateY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y;
        translateY.value = Math.max(translateY.value, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
        console.log(translateY.value);
      })
      .onEnd(() => {
        if (translateY.value > -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3) {
          scrollTo(0);
        } else if (translateY.value < -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 1.5) {
          scrollTo(MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
        }
        console.log('end: ' + translateY.value)
      });

    const rBottomSheetStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
      const borderRadius = interpolate(
        translateY.value,
        [MAX_TRANSLATE_Y + 50, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y],
        [25, 5],
        Extrapolate.CLAMP
      );

      return {
        borderRadius,
        transform: [{ translateY: translateY.value }],
        maxHeight: 500,
      };
    });

 

    return (
      <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.bottomSheetContainer, rBottomSheetStyle] }>
          <View style={styles.line} />
          {children}
        </Animated.View>
      </GestureDetector>
    );
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottomSheetContainer: {
    minHeight: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 50,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    position: 'relative',
    top: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 500,
    borderRadius: 25,
  },
  line: {
    width: 75,
    height: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginVertical: 15,
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
});

export default BottomSheet;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bar component will have the GestureHandler tied to it. Interpolate yTranslation into a value between 0 and 1. The Bar component's SharedValue is passed as prop so that other components in its parent contain utilize it:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ViewStyle,
  Dimensions,
  View,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  SharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  interpolate,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { GestureDetector, Gesture } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
type Props = {
  anim: SharedValue<number>;
  style?: ViewStyle;
};

const snapPoints = [0.2, 0.5, 0.8];

export default function Bar({ anim, style }: Props) {
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
    .onUpdate((e) => {
      // interpolate yTranslation to a value that snapPoints can work with
      anim.value = interpolate(
        e.translationY,
        [-height * 0.5, height * 0.5],
        [0, 1]
      );
    })
    // snap to nearest point
    .onEnd(() => {
      const snapPoint = snapPoints.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        const prevDist = Math.abs(prev - anim.value);
        const currDist = Math.abs(curr - anim.value);
        return prevDist < currDist ? prev : curr;
      }, snapPoints[0]);

      console.log('snapping to ', snapPoint);
      // animate snapping to snapPoint
      anim.value = withTiming(snapPoint);
    });

  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
      <View style={styles.barContainer}>
        <View style={styles.bar} />
      </View>
    </GestureDetector>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  barContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    width: '100%',
    //padding to make bar easier to press
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  bar: {
    backgroundColor: '#c4c4c4',
    width: '80%',
    height: 7,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 25,
  },
});
```

Now that translationY is a percentage it can be used to determine the amount of flex each view have:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import SliderBar from './SliderBar';
import View1 from './View1';
import View2 from './View2';
import { footerHeight, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, MAX_FLEX } from './Constants';

export default function App() {
  const barValue = useSharedValue(0.5);
  const view1Style = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      flex: barValue.value * MAX_FLEX,
    };
  });
  const view2Style = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      flex: Math.abs(barValue.value - 1) * MAX_FLEX,
    };
  });
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView
      style={{ width: ScreenWidth, height: ScreenHeight }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.viewStyle, view1Style]}>
          <View1 />
        </Animated.View>
        <SliderBar anim={barValue} />
        <Animated.View style={[styles.viewStyle, view2Style]}>
          <View2 />
        </Animated.View>
        <View style={styles.footer} />
      </View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    padding: 8,
    margin: 5,
  },

  viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#c4c4c4',
    flex: 1,
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: '#6f6f6f',
    height: footerHeight,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/XY8WlyHUD)

Comment: This is great! I do have a question though, i've noticed when I click/drag the line after I move it to a snap position, the line snaps back to the middle. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: I assume it has to be the interpolation. It expects that the drags will be some between half the screenHeight(positive and negative) and maps it to a value between 0 and 1. So when yTranslation is really small,  it will be interpolated to a value close 0.5. I think having an offset like they do [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/quickstart/) might fix this

Comment: I recently  was playing around with the `onChange` panhandler event and it  made me think that it would make it possible to avoid having to use an offset at all. You just add e.changeY to the sharedValue

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/pja8zBOHE